# Counting of squares

Tags: permutations

A rectangle can be divided into $n$ equal squares.
If the same rectangle can also be divided into $n+ 76$ equal squares then find $n$.

I tried with taking dimensions of squares as $x$ and $y$.
Then I made the respective lenghts and breadths 
equal for two cases. Also, I equated the combined areas, but then I am not able to find the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Let $w$ and $h$ be the width and height of the rectangle in arbitrary unit. 
WOLOG, we will assume $w \ge h$.

In order for the rectangle to be covered perfectly by $n$ squares. $w$ and $h$ need to be commensurable. i.e. $\displaystyle\;\frac{w}{h} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Choose a new unit so that $\displaystyle\;w, h \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ and $\gcd(w,h) = 1$.

If we can cover the rectangle by $n$ squares of side $s$, then both $\frac{w}{s}$ and $\frac{h}{s}$ have to integers. Furthermore, since $\left.\frac{w}{s}\right/\frac{h}{s} = \frac{w}{h}$ and $\gcd(w,h) = 1$, there is a $p \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ so that
$\frac{w}{s} = pw$ and $\frac{h}{s} = ph$. This implies $n = p^2 wh$.

By a similar argument, there is a $q \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ so that $n + 76 = q^2 wh$. This leads to

$$(q+p)(q-p)wh = 76 = 2^2\times 19\tag{*1}$$

Notice $q-p$ and $q+p$ has same parity, there are two possibilities:

1. Both $q-p$ and $q+p$ are odd

   In this case, $wh$ contains the $2^2$ factor from $76$.
   Since $19$ is a prime and $\gcd(w,h) = 1$, we find

$$(q+p, q-p, wh ) = (19,1,4) \implies (q,p,w,h) = (10,9,4,1)\\ \implies n = 9^2\times 4\times 1 = 324$$

2. Both $q-p$ and $q+p$ are even

   We can rewrite $(*1)$ as $$\frac{q+p}{2}\frac{q-p}{2} w h = 19$$ 
   Since $\frac{q+p}{2} > \frac{q-p}{2}$ are both positive integers, $\frac{q+p}{2}\frac{q-p}{2} > 1$. Since $19$ is a prime, this leads to
   $$\left(\frac{q+p}{2},\frac{q-p}{2}, wh \right) = (19,1,1) \implies (q,p,w,h) = (20,18,1,1)\\ \implies n = 18^2 \times 1^2 = 324$$

Combine these, we can conclude $n = 324$ is the **unique** solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The number $76$ equals $4 * 19$. Now as well-known the difference between two successive squares goes as $1, 3, 5, 7, 9...$ Based on this series we can easily establish that $19= 100 - 81 = 10^2 - 9^2$. The multiplicative factor $4$ can be taken into account without difficulty, since it equals $2$ squared. This way we arrive at the important intermediate result that the number $76$ can be expressed as the difference between two squares as follows:

$$76 = 400 - 324 = 20^2 - 18^2$$

Now if we take $324$ squares of length $10$, or $400$ squares of length $9$, both combinations have the same surface area ($= 32400$). From this we conclude that $N = 324$ is the solution.

Furthermore it follows that the rectangle has length $360$ and width $90$ (unless a square with sides $180$ is also allowed).

Comment: Is that a solution to the problem?

Comment: It might be useful to point out how to obtain $20^2-18^2$ without trial and error.  It's true that $76$ is small enough to apply trial and error, but the principle is useful for larger numbers—for instance, if the difference were $3076$ rather than $76$.

Comment: $76 = 4 * 19$. Now the difference between successive squares is $1, 3, 5, 7$ etc. This makes it easy to find two successive squares with a difference of $19$. Finally apply the factor $4$ which is obviously equal to $2$ squared.